# Replacing dots in file name with underscores except the extension

Tags: command-line, rename, mv

Can someone suggest on how to rename the file name:

```
head.body.date.txt
```

To:

```
head_body_date.txt
```

Is there a single line statement to do the rename in *Unix*?

Comment: Do you assume that `.tar.gz` is an extension? Also, welcome to U&L!

Comment: Do you really mean Unix as opposed to Linux? Which Unix?

Comment: The obvious answer is `mv head.body.date.txt head_body_date.txt`.  If you have other restrictions or real examples, then please update your question with these. As it stands now, it's unclear whether the question refers to a file with that explicit name, a single directory where all files have a particular format, or if you want to search a directory hierarchy for particular names and change these.

Answer (score 12):

Iterate over the filenames, and use Parameter expansion for conversion:

```
for f in *.*.*.txt; do i="${f%.txt}"; echo mv -i -- "$f" "${i//./_}.txt"; done
```

The parameter expansion pattern, `${f//./_}` replaces all `.`s with `_`s in the filename (`$f`).

The above will do a dry-run, to let the actual renaming take place, remove `echo`:

```
for f in *.*.*.txt; do i="${f%.txt}"; mv -i -- "$f" "${i//./_}.txt"; done
```

---

If you want to deal with any extension, not just `.txt`:

```
for f in *.*.*.*; do pre="${f%.*}"; suf="${f##*.}"; \
                     echo mv -i -- "$f" "${pre//./_}.${suf}"; done
```

After checking remove `echo` for actual action:

```
for f in *.*.*.*; do pre="${f%.*}"; suf="${f##*.}"; \
                     mv -i -- "$f" "${pre//./_}.${suf}"; done
```

---

Generic, for arbitrary number of dots, at least one:

```
for f in *.*; do pre="${f%.*}"; suf="${f##*.}"; \
                 mv -i -- "$f" "${pre//./_}.${suf}"; done
```

Comment: is there a general way if there is an arbitrary number of dots ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga Do: `for f in *.*; do ...; done`

Comment: I might suggest putting the `*.*` pattern straight in the example, since now the code looks like it works only with a fixed number of dots.

Comment: @ilkkachu Fair enough, edited.

Comment: Thank you so much heemay, it worked for me. and some learning!

Comment: Thank you so much @heemay it worked for me. and some learning!

Comment: @heemay Thank you so much it worked for me. and some learning!

Comment: @heemayl works pretty well and some learning!

Answer (score 5):

with `perl` based `rename`

```
$ rename -n 's/\.[^.]+$(*SKIP)(*F)|\./_/g' head.body.date.txt 
rename(head.body.date.txt, head_body_date.txt)
```

- `\.[^.]+$(*SKIP)(*F)` skip this pattern and look for alternate matches
- `|\./_/g` replace all `.` with `_`

Or, using negative lookahead

```
$ rename -n 's/\.(?![^.]+$)/_/g' head.body.date.txt 
rename(head.body.date.txt, head_body_date.txt)
```

Once this is okay, remove the `-n` option

Answer (score 4):

```
rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/_/g' *.txt
```

Uses regex replacement to find all but the last instance of `.` in the filename (non-capturing lookahead) and replace them with `_`. Generalises to `*.*` if you like.

(this particular version of `rename` seems to be installed via `util-linux`). I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04` (yes, severely out of date machine).

Answer (score 2):

`bash`:

```
old=head.body.date.txt oldb=${old%.*} olde=${old##*.} ; \
mv -- "$old" "${oldb//./_}.${olde}"
```

Comment: (1) You should use `mv --`, to guard against “old” filenames that begin with **`-`**. (2) You should put `$old` in quotes (`"$old"`), to guard against “old” filenames that contain spaces or characters that are special to the shell (like `*` and `?`). (3) Your answer fails in the somewhat pathological case in which the extension contains an underscore: `head.body.date.t_xt` gets renamed to `head_body_date_t.xt`.

Comment: @Scott, thanks.  The code is now tweaked as per all three items mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mv`, `sed` and `rev` in one line:

```
mv "head.body.date.txt" "$(echo head.body.date.txt | rev | sed 's/\./_/2g' | rev)"
```

If you want to apply it on all `txt` files in current rep, using globs seems tricky because of how `mv` works, but you can do a `for` loop in a one-liner:

```
for file in *.txt; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | rev | sed 's/\./_/2g' | rev)"; done
```

Slightly longer, but you can match several patterns in your loop !

Comment: (1) Arrghhh! Don’t do `$(ls …)`; just do `for file in *.txt`. (2) You should use more quotes: `mv "$file" "$(…)"`.

Comment: Thank you Scott, duly noted and edited ! I am still a youngster in shell, please be gentle ;)

Comment: In hindsight, using `rename` like several others have suggested in their answers does sound simpler though...

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this one just yesterday. It's plain, simple, easy to understand.

eg Mary.had.a.little.lamb.mp3

name w/o extension
extension="${filename##*.}"

#extension w/o name

filename="${filename%.*}"
changes . to _
newfilename="$(rename 's/./_/g' "$filename")"
newestfilename="$newfilename"."$extension"

Mary_had_a_little_lamb.mp3

Note: the # and anything after are for explanation only and you do not have to use them.

requires perl rename

To do an entire folder, wrap in a 'for' loop

for w in *; do
the stuff above
done

I wasted a couple of hours trying to make it recursive to no avail. What I've done is
a) write the script to do one entire folder - do not try to make it recursive. Make it executable.

b) install 'worker' file manager from the repositories.

On the bottom of the screen is a purple stripe - click on it and see the bank of buttons change.

On the very top of the screen, extreme left you'll see an 'A'. to the right of the 'A' is a button with some sort of symbol on it. Left click brings up the settings menu.

Click 'button configuration' and you'll see a couple of banks of buttons you can scroll through the banks if you wish.

When you've chosen your button, click on it. A new window will open up. Enter what you want the button, like 'recursive . to _' without the quotes.
Two buttons above the blue hi-lited 'Configure' button is one that says 'Add Command'. Click it.

Click 'Own Command'

Click 'Okay'

Click 'Recursive' - check marks on the buttons are kind of hard to see.

Start mode should be 'normal mode'

You can use find button or type in the path beside it.

Lastly, hit any 'Okay' 'Save' buttons on your way out. After that, you know the drill. click on one of the panels to select it, navigate to the folder you want to do magi in. You can figure it out from there.

NOTE" I have tried off and on for over 10 years to get ffmpeg to recurse, once I figured it out and wrapped my 'do-this-to-one-entire-folder script, It recursed the  entire of branch of folder/subfolder/etc perfectly.

DISCLAIMER: I am only a worker user and have no other connection to it.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but this is more than a little unclear. What's that script looking thing in the beginning? How to run it? Why is perl `rename` required as it's not in the script? Doesn't the script do the job alone, how is `worker` related to all this? What "button" and "panels" are you talking about? Maybe edit your question, adding the full script (if that's what it is) complete with the `{ code }` brackets, clarifying screenshots etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
 mv head.body.date.txt head_body_date.txt
```

It is as simple as that for a single file at a time. You do no specify whether you would like this done recursively within a directory or to the whole directory at all, so that would be your most convenient, quick solution.

Comment: I don't get the minus votes here, this answer DOES exactly what OP is asking for within the constraints he exposed. The fact there are different and potentially more portable solutions does not mean this one is bad, the question called for it.